# iOS Use callback

Tags: ios, selector

Please excuse my English, I'm French.

So, I'm a newbie in iOS development.
I've developed a method which must call a callback function after async task.
I've made a search about selectors, but I can't really understand how does it works...

This is my code :

```
NSString *const BaseURLString = @"http://mywebsite.fr/";
+ (void) getAdverts:(SEL *)myselector {
// 1
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:BaseURLString]];

// 2
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[client getPath:@"jsoncall"
     parameters:nil
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
            NSArray *adverts = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Advert"];

            NSMutableArray *advertList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            Advert *advert = [[Advert alloc] init];

            [adverts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj ,NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
                advert.identifier = [(NSNumber *)[obj objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
                advert.title = [obj objectForKey:@"title"];
                advert.size = [obj objectForKey:@"size"];
                NSLog(@"ID:%d Size:%@", advert.identifier, advert.size);
                [advertList addObject:advert];
            }];

             // Use selector to callback a function
            [self performSelector:myselector withObject:@"test"];
        }
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                         message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [av show];

        }
 ];
}
```

The "caller" code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [ServerHelper getAdverts:@selector(mySelector)];
}

- (void)mySelector
{
    NSLog(@"selector ok");
}
```

Here the error :
unrecognized selector sent to class

Thanks a lot

Comment: what is the problem with the code?

Comment: Please look at my edit (error : unrecognized selector sent to class)

Comment: This looks suspect `[self performSelector:myselector withObject:@"test"];` Why are you passing a parameter to an selector that doesn't take any parameters?

Comment: Yes. As abizern said remove the parameter and set nil to object.

Comment: You might also consider being more modern and passing a block instead of a selector.

Comment: Ok I will have a look for blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't quite passing the selector correctly and you aren't calling it properly.

You don't want to pass a pointer to a `SEL`, you just need a `SEL`.  The method should be:

```
+ (void) getAdverts:(SEL)myselector {
```

However, at the moment you have:

```
[self performSelector:myselector withObject:@"test"];
```

In this instance `self` refers to the class in which the `getAdverts` class method has been defined.  Not an instance of the class which the `mySelector` instance has been declared.

If you want to do it this way you probably need to pass in the object that you want the selector to be called on. Your `getAdverts` method needs to be something like:

```
+ (void) getAdvertsWithTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)myselector {
```

and then you would callback using something like:

```
[target performSelector:myselector];
```

and call it as follows:

```
[ServerHelper getAdvertsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(mySelector)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The type you are looking for is selector (`SEL`) and you get a method's selector like this:

```
SEL littleSelector = @selector(littleMethod);
```

If the method takes parameters, you just put `:` where they go, like this:

```
SEL littleSelector = @selector(littleMethodWithSomething:andSomethingElse:);
```

Also, methods are not really functions, they are used to send messages to specific class (when starting with +) or specific instance of it (when starting with -). Functions are C-type that doesn't really have a "target" like methods do.

Once you get a selector, you call that method on your target (be it class or instance) like this:

```
[target performSelector:someSelector];
```

A good example of this is `UIControl`'s [addTarget:action:forControlEvents:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a) method you usually use when creating `UIButton` or some other control objects programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [ServerHelper getAdverts:@selector(mySelector:)];
}

- (void)mySelector:(id)object
{
    NSLog(@"selector ok");
}
```

It should work. mind the : after the selector, and the object argument added.